# AngularJS Value is NaN after assigned in promise success function

Tags: angularjs, variable-assignment, nan, angular-promise

I've been struggling with this the past few Hours and I don't know what to do about it. I am doing an AngularJS application and I use angular-timer Directive.
http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/

It works perfect when I dynamically assign TimerValue value to the end-time attribute in ng-repeat. But it fails when I use it in My Details page which is using routeParams

```
<timer end-time="itemDetail.startDate">
```

so on the Detail page when the user click somewhere he is getting redirected to /someurl/1 The page loads fine the iMages the text everything is working fine. But the timerValue is showing NaN everywhere here is the app structure I've been using

JSON data

```
[   
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "productTitle" : "Motorola 156 MX-VL",
        "imgUrl" : "app/assets/images/laptop.png",
        "itemPrice" : "170",
        "startDate" : 1431249465000
    }
]
```

Page controller

```
app.controller('detailsController',  ['$scope', '$routeParams','itemsService',
  function($scope, $routeParams,itemsService) {
    itemsService.getItemById($routeParams.itemId).then(function(data){
        $scope.itemDetail = data;
    });
 }]);
```

The factory

```
app.factory('itemsService',  ['$http','$filter',  function($http, $filter){
    var itemsService = {
            getAllItems: function() {
              // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
              var promise = $http.get('app/jsons/items.json').then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
              });
              // Return the promise to the controller
              return promise;
            }, getItemById : function(id) {
                var promise = $http.get('app/jsons/items.json').then(function (response) {

                    return $filter('filter')(response.data, {id: id})[0];
                 });
              // Return the promise to the controller

              return promise;

            }
          };
          return itemsService;
    }]);
```

And in the View I'm using it like this

```
<div class="large-12 columns" >
                    Remaning time: <timer end-time="startDate">{{days}} Days, {{hours}} Hours, {{minutes}} Minutes, {{seconds}} Seconds.</timer>
                </div>
```

The timer works if I put the Timestamp directly in the "end-time" attribute and it also work if I assign the Value directly in the controller

```
$scope.startDate = 1431249465000;
```

But it doesn't work if I do it like this:

```
<timer end-time="itemDetail.startDate">
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: check if itemDetail.startDate is string not num

Comment: This didn't help as well :|

Answer (score 0):

you needs eval expression for end-time attributes

```
<timer end-time="{{itemDetail.startDate}}">
```

Comment: This was one of the first thing i did when the Nan Problem Appear but. in This case the entire page is Breaking

Answer (score -1):

Okay guys. I found a solution that worked for me and its pretty easy though. It seems that the problem is related with the way how angular execute its methods. When i assign a filtered object to the $scope.itemDetail= filteredObj. And when i try to use the `itemDetail.startDate` in the html the value does not get resolved correctly and i see the NaNs. So this might work correctly when i hook up the Rest api which is still under development but for now i am using mockup jsons with dummy data, and god nows what is going on behind the scenes with Angular. The solution i used was simply to use ng-repeat instead of directly accessing the object property from the html. And it worked.

The solution

i added a ng-repeat directive to the parent div that holds my Item details. And simply accessing the properties like this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemDetails">
{{item.name}}
  Remaning time: <timer end-time="item.StartDate">{{days}} Days, {{hours}} Hours, {{minutes}} Minutes, {{seconds}} Seconds.</timer>
</div>
```

And in this case it works as it suppose to either way or another in my itemDetails object array i have only one Object since i filter the data according the ID that is passed from the $routeParams